# Hackerrank Binary Tree Nodes SQL solution. Please explain

Tags: mysql, sql, binary-tree

I'm trying to understand why the value of n = 5(from the image link e.g.) is not reported as Inner? Since second line of case query states to check n in every distinct p. So if n = 5 which is in p shouldn't it be reported as Inner? Is it because every second line case query is re checked by first line of case query??

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN P IS NULL THEN CONCAT(N, ' Root')
    WHEN N IN (SELECT DISTINCT P FROM BST) THEN CONCAT(N, ' Inner')
    ELSE CONCAT(N, ' Leaf')
    END
FROM BST
ORDER BY N;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Provide a table as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO.

Comment: *why the value of n = 5(from the image link e.g.) is not reported as Inner?* Because this row matches 1st condition `WHEN P IS NULL`. And 2nd condition won't be investigated for this row.

Answer (score 1):

A `SELECT CASE` expression will result in the evaluation of at most *one* `THEN` expression -- the first one that has a `WHEN` condition that satisfies.

Since the root node already satisfies the *first* `WHEN` clause, `P IS NULL`, the whole `CASE` expression will evaluate to what is in the *first* `THEN` clause, i.e. `CONCAT(N, ' Inner')`. In this case the rest of the `CASE` expression is not evaluated, even though the next `WHEN` condition would also be true.